# Wrong lat/long using fortify, broom::tidy

Tags: r, ggplot2, broom

I'm having some trouble with the broom::tidy function. This might be specific to my shapefile (which is a map of all rivers in Alaska).

I load the file using the readOGR function

```
shp <- readOGR(dsn = ".","mv_navigable_water_ln")
```

And then fortify the spatial data into a data frame using the broom::tidy function.

```
shp_points <- tidy(shp, region="group")
```

Which all seems to work. When I plot the points using ggplot it gives me a map that spatially makes sense.

```
ggplot(data=shape_points, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_path() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[map of alaska rivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgN2V.png)

However if you look at the axes the lat and long are in a format that I don't recognize. I don't see any obvious conversion factors for them either. Anyone else experience this?

Session info:
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgN2V.png) broom_0.4.2   dplyr_0.7.4   rgeos_0.3-25  ggplot2_2.2.1 rgdal_1.2-13  sp_1.2-5

Comment: Chances are, the data are projected. What did the metadata say?

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

After the first step

```
shp <- readOGR(dsn = ".","mv_navigable_water_ln")
```

Try transforming your CRS to EPSG:4326

```
library(sp)

shp <- spTransform(shp,"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

And then follow the rest of your steps.  Now your axes should be latitude and longitude in decimal degrees

Comment: Thanks for your help! I received the following error message:

Error in spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) : 
  No transformation possible from NA reference system